# Validating time entered into textbox

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a textbox in which user can enter time (eg: 01:00) and also a drop down box for entering AM/PM fields. (Since the AM/PM field is used, 12-hour time format is used.)

The text box allows a max entry of 5 chars only (eg: 01:00).

1. How can I set the 3rd char as a default a colon `:`, so that the user simply has to enter only the time.
2. How to check if the time entered by the user is numeric or not?.
3. Autocomplete feature: for example, if the user enters 1 then it would automatically be set to 01:00
4. JavaScript Validations for 12-hour format. Eg: if user enters 13:00 then it should change to 01:00
5. How can  I append the text box time values with the am/pm value selected in the drop down box?.
6. Once the values are appended, automatically populate another text box (text box 2) with the result. Eg: 01:00 + pm should be set as 01:00p in the new text box (text box 2).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Better to have textbox with size and maxlength of 2 named "txtHours", colon as label (span tag) and another textbox named "txtMinutes". Much easier to manage.
2. Instead of checking, have `onkeypress` code that returns false when the key pressed is not a number thus allowing only digits.
3. Best be done in the `onblur` event, if the value is less than 10 add zero in the beginning.
4. Pretty simple script, though not trivial - use `%` operator.
5. Not sure what you mean? Append where?
6. `document.getElementById("textbox2").value = strAppendedText;`

That's the general idea, let me know if you need help implementing something best give it a try yourself first.

Comment: I agree with the 2 input approach, it's easier to figure out for you and the user.  Imagine what happens if you type 115 for 1:15, how do you know where to put the colon since you used a single digit hour.

Comment: @Zack good point, 115 can be either 1:15 or 11:05 it's not possible to know.

Comment: @Shadow & @Zack: Thanks for your help.Sorry, I didnt make point 5 clear. What I mean is,I want to append the AM/PM value selected from the dropdown to the time value selected from textbox 1 , and then immediately populate the result to textbox2.

Comment: @unos so 5 and 6 are actually one step.. anyway try writing yourself and ask if you hit any solid walls. By the way Zack didn't get notification, only the first `@` has effect.

Comment: ahh..ok.;). I have already written the code actually (won't be able to post it as it is confidential)..was just checking for any new ideas, such as yours. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @uno you can post only relevant parts if you need help fixing/improving them. :)